# NextJS/Django 404 page issue & Unhandled runtime error

Tags: django, next.js

So I am creating a blog using django as a backend, nextjs as a fronted.

I am having an issue with categories in navbar, as all of them are returning 404 error (just before 404, I get Unhandled runtime error for less than a second, I attached a screenshot

[image: error])

Anyway, here is my Navbar.js component, where I use categories

```
import Link from 'next/link'

  const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light'>
            <div className='p-2 text-muted'><Link className='navbar-brand' href={'/'}>5minRead</Link></div>
            <button className='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbarNavAltMarkup'
            aria-controls='navbarNavAltMarkup' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation'>
                <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
            </button>
            <div className='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarNavAltMarkup'>
                <div className='navbar-nav'>
                    <div className='p-4 text-muted'><a href={'/category/world'}>WORLD</a></div>
                    <div className='p-4 text-muted'><Link href={'/category/enviroment'}>ENVIROMENT</Link></div>
                    <div className='p-4 text-muted'><Link href={'/category/technology'}>TECHNOLOGY</Link></div>
                    <div className='p-4 text-muted'><Link href={'/category/culture'}>CULTURE</Link></div>
                    <div className='p-4 text-muted'><Link href={'/category/business'}>BUSINESS</Link></div>
                    <div className='p-4 text-muted'><Link href={'/category/health'}>HEALTH</Link></div>
                    <div className='p-4 text-muted'><Link href={'/category/travel'}>TRAVEL</Link></div>
                    <div className='p-4 text-muted'><Link href={'/category/fashion'}>FASHION</Link></div>
                    <div className='p-4 text-muted'><Link href={'/category/opinion'}>OPINION</Link></div>
                    <div className='p-4 text-muted'><Link href={'/subscribe'}>SUBSCRIBE</Link></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
    }

    export default Navbar
```

here is my Category.js component (any category click from Navbar should navigate here)

```
const Category = () => {
return (
    <div>
        category
    </div>
   )
}

export default Category
```

here is my views.py that contain APIView

```
class BlogPostCategoryView(APIView):
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

def post(self, request, format=None):
    data = self.request.data
    category = data['category']
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_created').filter(category__iexact=category)

    serializer = BlogPostSerializer(queryset, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and here is url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', BlogPostListView.as_view()),
  path('featured', BlogPostFeaturedView.as_view()),
  path('category', BlogPostCategoryView.as_view()),
  path('<slug>', BlogPostDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

and lastly here is models.py

```
class Categories(models.TextChoices):
    WORLD = 'world'
    ENVIROMENT = 'enviroment'
    TECHNOLOGY = 'technology'
    CULTURE = 'culture'
    BUSINESS = 'business'
    HEALTH = 'health'
    TRAVEL = 'travel'
    FASHION = 'fashion'
    OPINION = 'opinion'
```

I am new to NextJS, I used to work with django alone.  I think I am messing up the routing somewhere. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you set ``APPEND_SLASH`` to False in **settings.py** django appends ``/`` by default in your urls so it will accept request at ``/category/world/`` not ``/category/world``

Comment: Hi @Ankit Tiwari yes I have APPEND_SLASH = False i settings.py

Comment: Hello @DK26 you how you're fetching data can you provide you api url It should be ``http://127.0.0.1:8000/category``

Comment: Hi @AnkitTiwari, hmm, I think we are getting somewhere. I don't fetch category. Where would I put http://127.0.0.1:8000/category and how? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello @DK26 I'm not used to Next.js but I think it's follows same method as react so you shold check this post https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react

Comment: Where is `Category.js` located in your folder structure? Next.js has a [file system based routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction), files under the `pages` folder will define the possible routes.